# Не работает скрипт вывода даты и времени

Tags: javascript, html

Сценарий JavaScript, который выводит текущую дату и время в окне браузера (слева вверху страницы). В нужное место страницы вставлен следующий код, который ссылается на соответствующий файл скрипта, текст которого приведен ниже:

```
<script language=JavaScript src="../vnu_datestamp.js">
</script>
```

Код:

```
days = new Array("Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота");
months = new Array("Январь", "Февраль", "Март", "Апрель", "Май", "Июнь", "Июль", "Август", "Сентябрь", "Октябрь", "Ноябрь", "Декабрь");

function renderDate() {
    var mydate = new Date();
    var year = mydate.getYear();
    if (year < 2000) {
        if (document.all) year = "19" + year;
        else year += 1900;
    }
    var day = mydate.getDay();
    var month = mydate.getMonth();
    var daym = mydate.getDate();
    if (daym < 10) daym = "0" + daym;
    var hours = mydate.getHours();
    var minutes = mydate.getMinutes();
    var dn = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        dn = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
    if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
    document.writeln("<FONT COLOR=\"#000000\" FACE=\"Verdana,arial,helvetica,sans serif\" size=\"1\"><B> ", days[day], " ", daym, " ", months[month], " ", year, "</B> | ", hours, ":", minutes, " ", dn, "</FONT><BR>");
}

renderDate();
```

Содержимое файла urok_19.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Использование скриптов
</title>
</head>
<body>
<script language=JavaScript src="../vnu_datestamp.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам код рабочий(если вставить его непосредственно в страницу). Проверяйте путь. Думаю, проблема в нем.

Если оба файла лежат в одной папке, то надо писать

```
src="./vnu_datestamp.js"
```

./ - синоним текущей папки
../ - родительская папка
/ - корневая папка

P.S. вместо language="JavaScript" лучше использовать type="text/javascript". Но это некритично.

Comment: у меня в одной папке лежат оба файла т.е. vnu_datestamp.js и urok_19.html

выше я разместила код html файла

Comment: Если они оба лежат в одной папке, то следует писать 

    src="./vnu_datestamp.js"

так как две точки - переход в родительскую папку.